# PromiseKit catch or perform operation without changing type

Tags: swift, promisekit

I have a function that returns a Promise of type T, but I want to both catch, and perform an operation on the result without changing the return type of the promise while keeping the promise chain. This is a simplified version of my workaround but I'm assuming there's a better way to do it with PromiseKit.

```
func createItem() -> Promise<T> {
    let promise = Client.shared.createItem(with: item).map({ (item) -> ItemModel in
        self.update(item)
        return item
    })
    promise.catch { (error) in
        self.error = error
    }
    return promise
}
```